# aspectj: why advice cannot be applied?

Tags: java, aspectj

I've created very basic aspectJ project. I have no idea why advice cannot be applied.

annotation

```
import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)  
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)  
@Documented  
public @interface Conditional {  
    String value();  
}
```

and aspectJ class:

```
@Aspect
public class AspectE {

    @Around("call(@Conditional * *.*(..)) && @annotation(conditional)" )
    public Object condition(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Conditional conditional) throws Throwable {

        System.out.println("entry point says hello!");
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
}
```

main:

```
public class Main {

    @Conditional("")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("main good morning");
    }
}
```

Could you please tell me what I should change to receive both messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is because of the `call(@Conditional * *.*(..))` which basically weaves the callers , the caller in this specific case is the command line and so there is no weaving happening.

You should probably change it to execution instead, that should work.

`@Around("execution(@Conditional * *.*(..)) && @annotation(conditional)" )`

Comment: I've changed it to `"execution(@EntryPoint * *.*(..))"` and surprisingly it works. Could you explain why? I find it interesting.

Comment: Yes, if you have a `call..`, aspectj weaves the callers, so if method1 calls method2, then method1 will be changed to have the `@Around` logic around it, method2 will be untouched. In your case method2 happens to be the main method which will not be touched at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [AspectJ weaver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_weaver) in order to apply your aspect `AspectE` to the Java class `Main`. If you're using Maven I would recommend to use [aspectj-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/).

Comment: Before using Maven I'd like to compile project by eclipse compiler. Advice which aren't based on annotations are seen. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

1. Either your advice must `proceed(conditional)` or, if you do not need the object bound to a variable, remove the binding.
2. Your pointcut matching problem is that there is no place inside your application which calls `main` (the Java command line does that), only a place where the method is executed, so you want to change that part of your pointcut to `execution(@Conditional * *.*(..))`.
3. To simplify things, you can remove either part of the pointcut, because both ones will match without redundantly connecting them by `&&`.

So the simplest version of the aspect in plain AspectJ syntax is:

```
public aspect AspectE {
    Object around() : @annotation(Conditional) {
        System.out.println("entry point says hello!");
        return proceed();
    }
}
```