# AspectJ & Maven warning: "Advice defined in ... has not been applied?"

Tags: java, maven, web-applications, jax-rs, aspectj

I'm trying to weave some aspects at compile time into a project that becomes a WAR.  The aspects advise classes that are within the same project (though in different packages).

I get the warning:

```
Advice not applied
```

My aspect is not being executed.  Here's my setup:

annotation FooAnnotation.java:

```
package a;
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface FooAnnotation {}
```

aspect FooAdvice.aj:

```
package a;
public aspect FooAdvice {
    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(FooAdvice.class);

    Object around() : call( @FooAnnotation * *(..)) {   
        log.info(String.format("Testing around"));
        return proceed();
    }
}
```

I also tried the annotation:

```
@Around("call( @FooAnnotation * *(..))")
public Object checkFoo( ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
```

As far as I can tell, my pointcut specification is correct, but for some reason the ajc compiler isn't playing ball.

Class FooClass.java:

```
package b;
@ApplicationPath("/service")
@Path("/{param}")
@Produces("application/json")
@Provider
public class FooClass {

    @POST
    @PUT
    @Path("/{context}/{resource}")
    @FooAnnotation
    public String updateResource(...) {}
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>zzz.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>yyy.artifact</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>yyy.name</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <javaVersion>1.6</javaVersion>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.7.2</org.aspectj-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            ... stuff ...
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${javaVersion}</source>
                    <target>${javaVersion}</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!--
                    Have to use version 1.2 since version 1.3 does not appear to work
                    with ITDs
                -->
                <version>1.4</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <!--
                        You must use Maven 2.0.9 or above or these are ignored (see
                        MNG-2972)
                    -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <!-- <goal>test-compile</goal> -->
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <outxml>true</outxml>
                    <source>${javaVersion}</source>
                    <target>${javaVersion}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aha!  Found the answer here:

[aspectj: why advice cannot be applied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053453/aspectj-why-advice-cannot-be-applied)

It has nothing to do with maven.

The reason is that in my example, the method is being called from within the jax-rs framework by indirect loading.  The `call()` advice wants to weave the caller, but the ajc compiler can't know where the caller is.  The fix is to change the advice to `execution()` thusly:

```
Object around() : execution(@FooAnnotation * *(..)) {...}
```

This differs because it weaves around the execution (which ajc can find), rather than the caller.

Done.

Comment: Unfortunately, I discovered that using the `execute()` advice causes the method to be mangled to the point that the jax-rs reflecting loader throws VerifyError messages during loading, so AOP isn't a good choice for jax-rs web services.